# How to convert `fs2.Stream[IO, T]` to `Iterator[T]` in Scala

Tags: scala, type-level-computation, fs2

Need to fill in the methods `next` and `hasNext` and **preserve** laziness

```
new Iterator[T] {
  val stream: fs2.Stream[IO, T] = ...

  def next(): T = ???
  def hasNext(): Boolean = ???

}
```

But cannot figure out how an earth to do this from a `fs2.Stream`?  All the methods on a `Stream` (or on the "compiled" thing) are fairly useless.

If this is simply impossible to do in a reasonable amount of code, then that itself is a satisfactory answer and we will just rip out `fs2.Stream` from the codebase - just want to check first!

Comment: You can't, not in general, `Iterator` would not allow expressing things like concurrency. - Why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: This is definitely an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) ... There should be a special checkbox for this sort of questions in the "Close" menu.

Comment: @Dima If converting from one collection type of thing to another collection type of thing is a "strange problem to solve", I guess they should remove `toList`, `toMap`, `toArray`, `toIterator`, etc from the standard Scala library?  Obviously users of those methods are "definitely" just XY-problems.

In fact why do we even need a standard Scala library? I mean surely every possible abstraction is actually just an XY problem?  In fact isn't like the whole theory of abstraction, algebra, category theory and even generalised mathematical solutions just another case of XY problem?

Comment: @Dima we can go further.  You need to eat right (Problem X)? Do you grow all the food yourself? or do you first earn money Y, then go to a shop and buy food?  Because if you do the latter that is "definitely" an XY-problem and "leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy".  Dima, joking aside, it turns out that abstractions and breaking problems down into smaller easier to solve problems is super useful, and that is what I'm doing here :)

Comment: @samthebest `fs2.Stream` is not a "collection", it is a processing abstraction for computing side-effects (as Luis pointed out, you could treat a _pure_ stream as a collection, but that's just one special case). 
For your "need to eat" example, a possible way to formulate an "XY-problem" would be something like "How do I use nano-technology to assemble a chicken egg from atoms?"

Comment: @samthebest the point is that if you described you _actual_ problem ("X"), which is probably, access the contents of the stream and process/transform it in some way, you would likely quickly get some useful answers (or even found them yourself, by reading the [documentation](https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.13/2.5.11/fs2-core_2.13-2.5.11-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream.html)), such as using `map`, `flatMap`, `collect` or one of the numerous other methods on the Stream class rather than engaging into this pointless discussion.

Comment: @Dima I don't understand why we are discussing what `fs2.Stream` is, and what it is not. OP's use case seems clear enough... they is asking whether they can build an iterator from fs2.Stream. And the answer is that it's weird thing and impossible to do in a sane manner. The main thing to note here is that... their requirement is crystal clear... they are simply asking whether it can be done or not. It might be a weird thing to do from the `fs2` perspective... it might even seem like a absurd thing... but it's a valid requirement none the less.

Comment: @sarveshseri yes, they are asking how to build an iterator ... because they think they need to build it to solve some actual problem. But they are not telling us what that problem is, and building an iterator is almost certainly a wrong way to solve it.

Comment: @Dima, you are correct, it may well me I don't need to build an iterator from a Stream, I've intentionally abstracted away from a very vast context.  Solving this particular problem is just one in a very long complex chain.  Let me explain my _actual_ problem.  So I need food and shelter for myself and my family to survive.  Can you help find an optimal solution to this please?

Comment: Joking aside, I just wanted to know if this is easy or not.  If it's not easy, we just won't use the framework.  The nice thing about `Iterator` is it composes, it's native, it doesn't leak.  So if we can wrap a Stream in an Iterator, we don't leak out all the opinionated frameworkyness to the rest of the codebase.

Comment: @samthebest the decision to use the framework should be based on the benefits you get from using it, rather than simplicity of converting things to `Iterator`. Frameworks aways come with overheads and tradeoffs. If you do not have a _specific reason_  to use a particular framework, you shouldn't be using it, _even if_ it was easy to convert its primitives to iterators. 
And, yes, if you are looking for food, I can direct you to a grocery store or a food bank, depending on your financial situation. But if instead you asked me how to make an egg from atoms, I'd just say it is impossible.

Comment: @Dima I have a general preference for libraries that expose native scala types, or easy conversions to them, because such libraries compose with all other libraries.  Stream only composes with Stream, it doesn't compose with StreamBar from Bar library, it doesn't compose with Scala collections, etc.  Secondly, replacing a library that exposes native types with another library is easy without having to refactor Call sites.

Comment: @samthebest That's a valid point, and essentially the same thing I was saying earlier: unless you have a _specific reason_ to use a library, do not use it, stick with core scala. In fact, I go even further: EVEN IF it does provide you with a way to convert something to iterator, STILL do not use it unless you can explain exactly why you need it. I have seen too many to count "runaway" codebases where people had a field day, with cats, and zio, and scalaz, and doobie and shmoobie, having made their code impossible to read, troubleshoot or maintain for the sake of using a "cool library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs2.Stream`, while similar in concept to `Iterator`, cannot be converted to one while preserving laziness. I'll try to elaborate on *why*...

Both represent a pull-based series of items, but the *way* in which they represent that series and implement the laziness differs too much.

As you already know, `Iterator` represents its pull in terms of the `next()` and `hasNext` methods, both of which are synchronous and blocking. To consume the iterator and return a value, you can directly call those methods e.g. in a loop, or use one of its many convenience methods.

`fs2.Stream` supports two capabilities that make it incompatible with that interface:

- `cats.effect.Resource` can be included in the construction of a Stream. For example, you could construct a `fs2.Stream[IO, Byte]` representing the contents of a file. When consuming that stream, even if you abort early or do some strange `flatMap`, the underlying `Resource` is honored and your file handle is guaranteed to be closed. If you were trying to do the same thing with iterator, the "abort early" case would pose problems, forcing you to do something like `Iterator[Byte] with Closeable` and the caller would have to make sure to `.close()` it, or some other pattern.
- Evaluation of "effects". In this context, effects are types like `IO` or `Future`, where the process of obtaining the value may perform some possibly-asynchronous action, and may perform side-effects. Asynchrony poses a problem when trying to force the process into a synchronous interface, since it forces you to block your current thread to wait for the asynchronous answer, which can cause deadlocks if you aren't careful. Libraries like cats-effect strongly discourage you from calling methods like `unsafeRunSync`.

`fs2.Stream` does allow for some special cases that prevent the inclusion of Resource and Effects, via its `Pure` type alias which you can use in place of `IO`. That gets you access to [`Stream.PureOps`](https://javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-core_2.13/latest/fs2/Stream$$PureOps.html), but that only gets you methods that consume the whole stream by building a collection; the laziness you want to preserve would be lost.

Side note: you *can* convert an Iterator to a Stream.

The only way to "convert" a Stream to an Iterator is to consume it to some collection type via e.g. `.compile.toList`, which would get you an `IO[List[T]]`, then `.map(_.iterator)` that to get an `IO[Iterator[T]]`. But ultimately that doesn't fit what you're asking for since it forces you to consume the stream to a buffer, breaking laziness.

@Dima mentioned the "XY Problem", which was poorly-received since they didn't really elaborate (initially) on the incompatibility, but they're right. It would be helpful to know *why* you're trying to make a Stream-to-Iterator conversion, in case there's some other approach that would serve your overall goal instead.

Comment: I think what we are fogetting here is that OP's objetive is not "using fs2 in their project". It is actually solving whatever problem statement they have. If `fs2` is not fitting their usecase, why should they stick to it. Why should they forget their actual problem and struggle with `fs2` compatibility with whatever `Iterator` based Java / Scala library used in the project ? Won't that be the real XY problem.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan and @sarveshseri.  Indeed we will go ahead and just not use `fs2`.  The dev in my team who brought it in obviously wasn't fully aware how frameworky and inflexible it is.  We will just find a lower level, more composable library instead.

Comment: @samthebest calling **fs2** not composable or inflexible; or at least less than `Iterator`, is either a bad joke or a very uninformed take. - `Iterator` being native is not really a good point IMHO, but your mileage can vary; I never bought the argument of not wanting to add dependencies. - Saying it doesn't leak almost also feel like a bad joke; but it seems you are using the word with a different meaning than I. - Anyways, you are indeed correct that **fs2** is intended to be used across the whole application as a foundational library, just like `IO` or `Future` may _"infect"_ the whole code

Comment: ... However, it is also very feasible to use **fs2** in the small and interoperate with external systems; both as a consumer and as a producer. And, IME _(limited TBH)_, doing so is usually straightforward. - Of course, I won't make the hot take that it will always be the case, your case seems to be the particular case where it isn't, but I am still convinced that at a meta-level it is possible; sadly it seems your application is structured around blocking synchronous processing which is exactly what libraries like **fs2** aim to avoid since that is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Anyways, as a final note, I don't have the time to write all the code right now, but I think you can convert a **fs2** `Stream` into an `Iterator` using an intermediate `Queue`, a couple of `unsafeRunSync` and launching an asynchronous process. The idea is that you would enqueue all the elements of the `Stream` in the `Queue` launch that in the background and then implement the `Iterator` methods in terms of the `Queue`; just used a bounded _(or maybe even a synchronous)_ `Queue` to keep backpressure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, I had that idea also, but struggled to (in my head) implement `hasNext`.  I.e., if we use `Stream.map` to enqueue, there is no way in the scope of `map` lambda to know when the stream is done.

As a hilarious hack, I then thought, we could use `sliding(2)`, which would return a 1-element list when the Stream is exhausted.

Comment: @samthebest It's not that `fs2` is frameworky or inflexible. Infact `fs2` is very flexible, extensible and highly composable. `fs2` solves a very much common (but complex) problem of flexible represnetation, handling and processing of data streams while allowing (and even mixing) serial, parallel, synchronous and asynchronous components. You requirement is kind of "how do I fit a nuclear weapon in my pistol". And the answer is - You just don't (even if you could). Nothing wrong with normal bullets.

Comment: @samthebest Although requirement is always the top priority (and we should prioritise), it does not mean that we call a modern superb tool as inflexible or in-composable for being incompatible with our rigid (and old) requirement. `Iterator` infterface is the real inflexible thing in this discussion, which was created many many years back as very rigid solution to a very general use case. It simply does not allow for any flexibility and compatibilty with regards to modern requirements of parallel and asynchronous use cases.

Comment: @sarveshseri it's easy to convert `Iterator` to any stream in any library.  Any streaming library that obstructs converting to `Iterator` thus blocks composition with other libraries.  Here by leaky I mean if I use Stream in one method, it seems all calling methods must alter their signature also. The type leaks out across the whole codebase, which makes it a poor abstraction.  Frameworks are evil, libraries compose.

Comment: @samthebest that is because of the flexibility of libraries (including `fs2`) that they allow creation from multiple sources. Not the other way around.